# kohana get next elements of a collection

Tags: orm, kohana

I have a collection of elements :

```
$products_asc =Model::factory('product')->sale($sale_id)->category($category_id)->order_by('product_id', 'asc')->find_all();
```

and I want to make a next-previous navigator into this elements. (of course, for getting the previous ones I will have a `$products_desc` ordering)

My problem is: I want to make a function having the signature:

```
public function get_next_product($category, $sale, $id_product)
```

that will always give me the next product id. but I don't know how to do it. How exactly can i get the next element of the collection having only all the elements sorted ascending by the :

```
$products_asc =Model::factory('product')->sale($sale_id)->category($category_id)->order_by('product_id', 'asc')->find_all();
```

Comment: the signature of the function is not a must, i mean i can change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the solution - for those who may also be in need:

```
        $previous = Model::factory('product')->sale($sale_id)->order_by('product_id','desc')->where('product_id', '<', $id)->find();    
        $next = Model::factory('product')->sale($sale_id)->where('product_id', '>', $id)->find();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Database_Result` is a kind of [`Iterator`](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) object. Why dont use `next($products_asc)` and `prev($products_asc)` functions?

Comment: if i try like this the output is literally :   product_id . no numeric id practically